# Change data in parent view from child view IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

My main(root) view X is being created with some data from method `populateMainScreen()`.

By click on one button inside main view X, child view Y appears on the screen.

How do I trigger this populateMainScreen() method of X, from Y which should cause view X to be changed.

If I navigate to it at any time in the future, the new update version should be visible.

Comment: There is very simple way : [Y superview] is X.

Comment: Could you revise the question to clarify the relationship between X and Y? Is Y a subview of X, or are X and Y the respective views of two view controllers in a parent/child relationship?

Comment: @Caleb Y is subview of X

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow This is confusing, since you say "if I navigate to it at any time in the future..." If Y is a subview of X, that means that X and Y are both visible at the same time. In other words, Y is visually contained within X. If there's navigation involved, you must be talking about separate views and view controllers on a navigation stack.

Comment: @Caleb sorry for sounding confusing I'm still learning the basics. I though only way to navigate to other view would be to add it as a current views subview.

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow No worries -- it's very common for people new to the platform to confuse 'view' and 'view controller', and it sounds like that's what's happening here. Make sure that you understand the difference between the two kinds of objects, and how they relate to each other.

Answer (score 2):

In a proper MVC implementation, you'd have the view controllers for both X and Y reading the data they need from some common set of model objects. Y shouldn't have to do anything special to get X to display the proper data; Y only needs to make its changes to the model object(s). Then, when X reappears, its controller would again fetch the data that it needs from the model. If the model changed, that change will naturally be reflected in X (and Y, and any other view that displays data from the same model).

Another approach, which is useful if you don't have a data model, or if your model doesn't store the data that Y modifies, is to have X's controller keep a reference to Y's controller. It's likely that X's controller created Y's controller (since you indicate that there's a parent/child relationship between them), so it's easy for X's controller to stash a reference to Y's controller in an instance variable or property. In it's `-viewWillAppear` method, X's controller can check that property; if it's not nil, it can retrieve whatever information it needs from Y's controller. It would then set the property to nil:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear
{
    if (self.ycontroller != nil) {
        self.person.name = self.ycontroller.name;
        self.person.address = self.ycontroller.address;
        self.ycontroller = nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Superview is accessible (as mentioned by NeverBe), but if you want to access the view controller, the object oriented way is through delegation. So you set the delegate property on view controller of Y to be the view controller of X, then send methods through the delegate. You can define non-standard methods through a protocol.

You could update the model as mentioned Caleb, too - either way is fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options

- Have the child view post an NSNotification, and have the parent be an observer for that notification, pass the data in the notification.
- Put your data in a singleton object that both views can reference
- Give the child a reference to a method in the parent (possibly by declaring a protocol)